# sql server KILL session ID

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, database-design, database-connection

Problem Statement:

We have sql server for our application. and our application is using WorkflowGen dll. We received a new version of dlls from Workflow Gen and deployed some sql scripts in SQL server which are a part of the new version. Since then at a specific time we are getting a block in sql server and so we can't have our application loaded.

Well we setup call with SQL server team and they KILL the SesionID's and after that the application started to work as it was normally. And this issue started to occur daily and we don't know

1. for whom the session has been created
2. Why it stays and stop the application from running.
3. What and where the actual problem is?
4. How to rectify the issue , so that it wont occur again.

Comment: Blocking is due to bad code or query plans. Since the problem started after the new version was installed, I suggest you contact the vendor.

Comment: bad code you mean some kind of extended procedure issue? because this issue was not there in lower environments...like staging where only one application server is there....but the issue comes in production environment where multiple application servers are there...

Comment: Not necessarily an extended stored procedure; any SQL query. Blocking will occur only when concurrent queries contend for the same resource and exacerbated by suboptimal execution plans and concurrent queries. I can see how blocking is more likely with multiple app servers but knowing nothing about WorkFlowGen, I think vendor assistance is your best resource.

Comment: ok Dan will contact vendor ..Thanks

Comment: The SQL Server team should also see what's running etc. You might want to delete this question or at least change the title completely.